# Bluetooth and playlists on iOS

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, bluetooth, playlists

I'm getting tired of navigating my playlists all the time. I have iOS development tools, so I'm wondering if I can solve this problem...

What I would like to do is have an app where I can associate a playlist with a specific Bluetooth device (that I'm already paired with). When the known Bluetooth device connects, continue playing that playlist from where it was when it last disconnected.  I.e. when I'm in the car, play my car playlist, when I'm at work, play my work playlist.

The little information I've found about Bluetooth programming on iOS suggests that this is not currently possible from MonoTouch.

Is this true? Does anyone here have/know about an app that does anything similar? There aren't many music playing apps on the App Store, so I'm guessing this is not going to be an easy task.

Comments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple is going to provide any APIs that would allow an app running in the background to be notified when a bluetooth device connects.

I think what you're asking can't be done on iOS--either with Objective-C or MonoTouch. The limitation here is what APIs Apple provides, not something with MonoTouch.

Now, you might possibly be able to achieve the following in a non-event driven manner:

- User presses a button, or foregrounds/opens your app
- Look up the currently active bluetooth device if there is one
- Play a specific track/playlist